# Missing method applications should be parenthesized

Tags: f#

I read xml file and want to compare the attribute value.

```
let xname name = XName.Get name
let xattr (elem: XElement) (name:string) = elem.Attribute(xname name).Value

let loc (filename:string) (location:string) = 
    query {
        for doc in XDocument.Load(filename).Descendants(xname location) do
        where (xattr doc "name").isEqual(location)
        select doc
    }
```

On the line `where (xattr doc "name").isEqual(location)` the compiler complains

```
Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the compiler is telling you exactly what you need to do.

In this case follow the second hint: parenthesized

Rewrite the expression:

```
(xattr doc "name").isEqual(location)
```

as

```
((xattr doc "name").isEqual(location))
```

You may be wondering why is he asking me to do so? The reason is because he doesn't know if an argument is just one argument or if there are more.

For example consider this function call:

```
function1 arg1 ()
```

it's two arguments, but if arg1 is a function with no parameters and you wnat to invoke it, it should be:

```
function1 (arg1 ())
```

Comment: How you do know all about f#. Are you f# master? Thanks very much.

Comment: No, I just use it everyday, answering questions here is also a good exercise for my F# fluency.